# Measurable functions (Integral)

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Let $\sigma_x$ be a measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R^n})$.

$\sigma_x(F):=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }x \in F\text{  }\\0,&\text{otherwise } \end{cases}\quad$

How to prove that all maps $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are integrable with respect to $\sigma_x$?

I know that $\int_\mathbb{R}g=g(x)$.

I tried to use that:

$\int_\mathbb{R}|g| d\sigma_x= |g(x)|<\infty$ so all $g$ are integrable with respect to $\sigma_x$

But I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: Your approach is correct.

Comment: You may also want to state that all $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ functions are measurable because all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are $\sigma_x$-measurable, so we don't need to worry about measurability of functions at all.

Comment: For a rigorous proof starting with definition of integral you have to first verify the equation $\int g d\sigma_x=g(x)$ for simple functions the take limits. Measurability is no issue because you are taking power set as the sigma algebra.